# $m(E_i)=\infty \space \forall i$ and $m(E)=const$

Tags: sequences-and-series, measure-theory

> $E ↘  \bigcap_n^\infty E_k$. Is it possible to construct the sequence $E_k$, $E_k \supset E_{k+1}$, such that $m(E_i)=\infty\quad\forall i$ and
>
> 1. $m(E)=\infty$ ?
> 2. $m(E)=0$ ?
> 3. $m(E)=\text{const} \neq0$ ?

I'm given this problem and I try to find such sequences.

1. It might is this sequence: $E_n=\big [- \frac{1}{n},\infty \big )$
2. It is easy to see that $E_n=(n,\infty)$ is a good sequence.

But what about the 3 one? Any help would be wonderful.

Comment: Did you swap 1. and 2. in your answer?

Comment: @ClementC. oops sorry, my bad. Thank you!

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 3), try $E_{n}=(-\infty,-1-n]\cup[-1,1]\cup[1+n,\infty)$.

Answer (score 1):

If you have 2. (with say $E_i \subseteq [0,\infty)$ for all $i$), you get 3. by setting $E_i' = [-2,-1]\cup E_i$ for all $i$. Then the constant is $1$.

For another constant, say $\alpha$, replace $[-2,-1]$ by $[-1-\alpha,-1]$.